# How to change color of text when UI gets updated in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="DomainExperience.Pane.DomainFile.DomainAnalysisPaneResultsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:domainExperience="clr-namespace:DomainExperience"
             xmlns:domainFile="clr-namespace:DomainExperience.Pane.DomainFile"
             Background="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"
             Foreground="{DynamicResource VsBrush.WindowText}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="MyToolWindow">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <domainFile:StatusColoredDataTemplateClass x:Key="StatusColoredDataTemplate" />
    </UserControl.Resources>    

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" CellTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource StatusColoredDataTemplate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And then, I created the following class

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DomainExperience.Pane.DomainFile
{
    public class StatusColoredDataTemplateClass : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            // Some logic here that I haven't defined yet...
        }
    }
}
```

The intention here is to change the color of the text that goes into the Status column depending on its content. I want to have Green text when the result is Passed and red text when it is Failed.

I've read that I should create a class that implements a DataTemplateSelector. However, I am not able to hit a breakpoint in this class whenever the Panel that is related to this XAML gets updated.

1. What is wrong in my XAML logic?
2. Am I missing something else maybe on my ViewModel logic?
3. What sort of code do I need to implement in my class to change the color of the text?

Thanks!

UPDATE: The Results property is associated to the following class

```
public class ResourceStaticAnalysisResults
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> ErrorList { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DataTemplateSelector` is overkill because you don't need to change the `DataTemplate` itself, just a property of one of its controls. Instead, you can define a single, fixed `DataTemplate` for that column and manage the change of color with a style:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StatusColoredDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type system:Boolean}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the column:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Header="Status"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"
    CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusColoredDataTemplate}" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess the DataTemplate should go into the <UserControl.Resources> right? Also, I noticed you have defined the DataType as boolean but the True and False flags are strings.. Should that be replaced by DataType="{x:Type system:String}"> ?

Comment: @user3587624 `DataType` should be set to whatever type the `GridViewColumn` is bound to, because that's the type that you're providing a template for.

Comment: In this case, True and False are strings ("True" and "False") so I set it to system:String. However, with your example, after the Pane gets refreshed nothing happens. The text continues black

Comment: Don't get confused by seeing them between quotation marks in XAML -that always applies to attribute values in XML.

Comment: I know, actually I changed the values to Passed and Failed (instead of True or False). They are definitely strings. I will update the question :)

Comment: I managed to make it work! Basically I had to get rid of the DisplayMemberBinding and to the Binding on the DataTemplate!